# mysql count the number of matches based on a column

Tags: mysql

This is my example dataset I have groups with students assigned to them as shown below

```
uid | groupid         | studentid
49  | PZV7cUZCnLwNkSS | wTsBSkkg4Weo8R3
50  | PZV7cUZCnLwNkSS | aIuDhxfChg3enCf
97  | CwvkffFcBCRbzdw | hEwLxJmnJmZFAic
99  | CwvkffFcBCRbzdw | OKFfl58XVQMrAyC
126 | CwvkffFcBCRbzdw | dlH8udyTjNV3nXM
142 | 2vu1eqTCWVjgE58 | Q01Iz3lC2uUMBSB
143 | 2vu1eqTCWVjgE58 | vB5s8hfTaVtx3wO
144 | 2vu1eqTCWVjgE58 | 5O9HA5Z7wVhgi6l
145 | 2vu1eqTCWVjgE58 | OiEUOXNjK2D2s8F
```

I am trying to output with the following information.
The problem I am having is the Group Size column getting it to output a count.

```
Studentid       | Groupid         | Group Size
wTsBSkkg4Weo8R3 | PZV7cUZCnLwNkSS | 2
aIuDhxfChg3enCf | PZV7cUZCnLwNkSS | 2
hEwLxJmnJmZFAic | CwvkffFcBCRbzdw | 3
OKFfl58XVQMrAyC | CwvkffFcBCRbzdw | 3
dlH8udyTjNV3nXM | CwvkffFcBCRbzdw | 3
```

I have researched if I can you can use a where clause in the count, and does not seem like it will let me do that.  I thought about doing a sum but couldn't make that happen either.  I feel like I am missing something simple.

Comment: That's what you want. The important thing to put in your question is **what you've tried**.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to solve this, is using a `JOIN` statement:

```
SELECT a.studentid AS Studentid, a.groupid AS Groupid, COUNT(*)
FROM table AS a
     JOIN table AS b ON a.groupid = b.groupid
GROUP BY a.studentid, a.groupid
```

So here we join the `table` with itself and use a `GROUP BY` to group on the `studentid` and `groupid` and then use `COUNT(*)` to count the number of rows in `b` that have the same `groupid`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM pony a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*), groupid
    FROM pony
    GROUP BY groupid
) b ON a.groupid = b.groupid
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT T1.Studentid, T1.Groupid, T2.GroupCount
FROM Your_Table T1
INNER JOIN ( SELECT Groupid, count(*) AS GroupCount FROM Your_Table GROUP BY Groupid ) T2
ON T1.Groupid = T2.Groupid
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

`SELECT COUNT(Groupid) AS Groupsize FROM table;`

It seems that what you're trying to do is simple. If I understand correctly, a simple *SELECT COUNT* statement. To exclude multiple returns of the same value, use *SELECT **DISTINCT** COUNT()*